# Transfer Learning/Fine Tuning - how to keep BatchNormalization in inference mode?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

In the following tutorial [Transfer learning and fine-tuning by TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/transfer_learning) it is explained that that when unfreezing a model that contains BatchNormalization (BN) layers, these should be kept in inference mode by passing `training=False` when calling the base model.

> […]
>
> #### Important notes about `BatchNormalization` layer
>
> Many image models contain `BatchNormalization` layers. That layer is a special case on every imaginable count. Here are a few things to keep in mind.
>
> - `BatchNormalization` contains 2 non-trainable weights that get updated during training. These are the variables tracking the mean and variance of the inputs.
> - When you set `bn_layer.trainable = False`, the `BatchNormalization` layer will run in inference mode, and will not update its mean & variance statistics. This is not the case for other layers in general, as weight trainability & inference/training modes are two orthogonal concepts. But the two are tied in the case of the `BatchNormalization` layer.
> - When you unfreeze a model that contains `BatchNormalization` layers in order to do fine-tuning, you should keep the `BatchNormalization` layers in inference mode by passing `training=False` when calling the base model. Otherwise the updates applied to the non-trainable weights will suddenly destroy what the model has learned.
>
> […]

In the examples they pass `training=False` when calling the base model, but later they set `base_model.trainable=True`, which for my understanding is the opposite of inference mode, because the BN layers will be set to trainable as well.

For my understanding there would have to be `0 trainable_weights` and `4 non_trainable_weights` for inference mode, which would be identical to when setting the `bn_layer.trainable=False`, which they stated would be the case for running the `bn_layer` in inference mode.

I checked the number of `trainable_weights` and  number of `non_trainable_weights` and they are both `2`.

I am confused by the tutorial, how can I really be sure BN layer are in inference mode when doing fine tuning on a model?

Does setting `training=False` on the model overwrite the behavior of `bn_layer.trainable=True`? So that even if the `trainable_weights` get listed with `2` these would not get updated during training (fine tuning)?

---

Update:

Here I found some further information: [`BatchNormalization` layer - on keras.io](https://keras.io/api/layers/normalization_layers/batch_normalization/).

> [...]
>
> #### About setting `layer.trainable = False` on a `BatchNormalization` layer:
>
> The meaning of setting `layer.trainable = False` is to freeze the layer, i.e. its internal state will not change during training: its trainable weights will not be updated during `fit()` or `train_on_batch()`, and its state updates will not be run.
>
> Usually, this does not necessarily mean that the layer is run in inference mode (which is normally controlled by the `training` argument that can be passed when calling a layer). "Frozen state" and "inference mode" are two separate concepts.
>
> However, in the case of the `BatchNormalization` layer, **setting** `trainable = False` **on the layer means that the layer will be subsequently run in inference mode** (meaning that it will use the moving mean and the moving variance to normalize the current batch, rather than using the mean and variance of the current batch).
>
> This behavior has been introduced in TensorFlow 2.0, in order to enable layer.trainable = False to produce the most commonly expected behavior in the convnet fine-tuning use case.
>
> Note that: - Setting `trainable` on an model containing other layers will recursively set the `trainable` value of all inner layers. - If the value of the `trainable` attribute is changed after calling `compile()` on a model, the new value doesn't take effect for this model until `compile()` is called again.

Question:

1. In case I want to fine tune the whole model, so I am going to unfreeze the `base_model.trainable = True`, would I have to manually set the BN layers to `bn_layer.trainable = False` in order to keep them in inference mode?
2. What does happen when with the call of the `base_model` passing `training=False` and additionally setting `base_model.trainable=True`? Do layers like `BatchNormalization` and `Dropout` stay in inference mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading the documentation and having a look on the source code of TensorFlows implementations of  `tf.keras.layers.Layer`, `tf.keras.layers.Dense`, and `tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization` I got the following understanding.

If `training = False` is passed on calling the layer or the model/base model, it will run in inference mode. This has nothing to do with the attribute `trainable`, which means something different. It would probably lead to less misunderstanding, if they would have called the parameter `training_mode` instead of `training`. I would have preferred defining it the other way round and calling it `inference_mode` .

When doing Transfer Learning or Fine Tuning `training = False` should be passed on calling the base model itself. As far as I saw until now this will only affect layers like `tf.keras.layers.Dropout` and `tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization` and will have not effect on the other layers.
Running in inference mode via `training = False` will result in:

- `tf.layers.Dropout` not to apply the dropout rate at all. As `tf.layers.Dropout` has no trainable weights, setting the attribute `trainable = False` will have no effect at all on this layer.
- `tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization` normalizing its inputs using the mean and variance of its moving statistics learned during training

The attribute `trainable` will only activate or deactivate updating the trainable weights of a layer.

Comment: a clear explanation but here I am confused if I want to train a ResNet-18 on Medical Images pre-trained on the image. so the domain is changed in this case should I freeze the BN layers? or It has less impact on it. I read a few papers and their comparison. They showed the results have less impact while `model.trainable = True` and freezing BN layers.

Comment: I agree that this explanation is not fully clear. After investigating for a bit I found this: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/transfer_learning#do_a_round_of_fine-tuning_of_the_entire_model where it specifically states that calling the model with training=False means BN layers will stay non-trainable even if you later call trainable=True

Answer (score 0):

Yes, After calling **base_model.trainable = True**, you need to set the BN layers to inference mode.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
for layer in base_model.layers:
    if isinstance(layer, layers.BatchNormalization):
        layer.trainable = False
```

And you can check each layer, whether its in training or inference mode:

```
for lnum, layer in enumerate(model.layers):
    print('layer: {}, name:{}, trainable:{}, dtype: {}'.format(lnum, layer.name, layer.trainable, layer.dtype))
```